# Warning: Use of undefined constant ​ - assumed '​' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Tags: php

Sale este error:

```
Warning: Use of undefined constant ​​ - assumed '​​' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) C:\xampp\htdocs\redsocial\Vista\home.php on line 62
```

Al hacer un foreach en la vista trae los datos pero sale ese error

```
<?php                      
$arrEspecialidades = ModelsHome::getAll();
foreach ($arrEspecialidades as $post){​​
?>
<?php echo $post->getcontent() ?>
<?php }​​ ?>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea 62? ¿`ModelsHome` es una clase? ¿`getAll()` es un método estático?

Comment: Y lo más importante, por qué abres y cierras tantas veces <?php ?>¿¿??¿?¿?¿? No tiene sentido, especialmente cuando ni siquiera estás poniendo html en medio... (cosa que tampoco se debería hacer, hay que evitar el spaghetti code!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

es un "problema" de tu version de php, tienes dos opciones, bajarte a una version inferior
o actualizar a la mas reciente y ver que pasa cuando vuelves a ejecutar el codigo.

Ahora es un warning y quizas en una version superior solo sera un E_NOTICE pero con eso ya podras encontrar la solucion para usar en tu codigo.